# as3 array error #1010

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

im basically trying to make a mini game where you have to dodge the oncoming objects by using the on-screen buttons (button left and right of the screen) it worked fine when i did it with an individual object then i decided to have more objects and make an array to hold them. thats when the error accrued.

the error is : 
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/cyclespeed()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your `cycle` [Array](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html) has 5 elements starting by the index **0** and ending by **4** :

> ... Array indices are zero-based, which means that the first element in the array is [0], the second element is [1], and so on.
>   
>   That's why your `for` loop should be like this :

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++) { }
```

OR

```
for (var i:int = 0; i <= 4; i++) { }
```

OR simply

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < cycle.length; i++) { }
```

- In your `cyclespeed` function, the value of your `i` var will be always **5**, which is the last value assigned to it in your `for` loop, and of course `cercle[5]` didn't exist that's why you got the `TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties` : `cercle[5]` is undefined and has not an `x` property.
- In your case you can use only one `Event.ENTER_FRAME` listener to do all the job like this :

  ```
  stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterThisFrame);
  function onEnterThisFrame(e:Event):void {
      box_MC.x -= 1;
      for (var i:int = 0; i < cycle.length; i++) {
          cycle[i].x += 1;
          if(box_MC.hitTestObject(cycle[i])) {
              trace ("true");
              box_MC.x += 4;
          }
      }
      if (movingdown == 1) {
          box_MC.y -=  4.5;
      } else if (movingup == 1) {
          box_MC.y +=  4.5;
      }
  }
  ```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep points to comment, so I'll critique what I saw in your code.

There are quite a few things wrong with the code.

This was declared twice, once in a for loop and one outside of the functions

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, cyclespeed);
```

You attached the "handleCollision" event to the stage and not a movieclip.

handleCollision refers to "cycle[i]" but i is out of scope since it is not apart of the for loop where i has been declared

```
function handleCollision( e:Event) : void {
    if(box_MC.hitTestObject(cycle[**i**])) {
        trace ("true");
        box_MC.x += 4;
    }
}
```

I would suggest building each piece one at a time because it seems like you are trying to do a lot at once, without actually getting anything to work.